# JVM target unable to import common classes in Kotlin multiplatform project

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

After creating a KMM project with both Android and iOS apps working without issues. I tried adding a new target JVM to the project to implement a basic backend service.

I have seen this working in other projects such as https://github.com/joreilly/PeopleInSpace but even if I think it must be right in front of me, I am not able to tell the difference with this one.

I created a sample project to reproduce it: https://github.com/RafaO/Surf you can check it out and see that inside the JVM client the class `Greeting` is not found.

Any ideas why this is happening are appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello! There are several problems with the JVM & Android Multiplatform libraries. Please have a look at this Meta Issue at the Kotlin Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42541. Some of its children might be describing exactly the same problem you face. If none of them do, consider filing an issue with the example project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's the only way, but I'm using multiplatform backend module with single jvm source set.

Example I've being using as a reference: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlinconf-app

my own setup:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
    application
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.0.0"
}

application {
    mainClass.set("io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain")
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    mainClassName = mainClass.get()
}

sqldelight {
    database("Database") {
        packageName = "com.app.server"
        dialect = "mysql"
    }
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        withJava()
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(project(":common"))
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            mapOf(
                "Main-Class" to application.mainClass.get()
            )
        )
    }
}

tasks.named<AbstractCopyTask>("jvmProcessResources") {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.WARN
}
```

target `run` for debug and `shadowJar` for making an executable.

Comment: thanks! This made the trick. Just pushed with the changes and works so far. :)