# Kotlin Multiplatform project import jvm variant

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have a Kotlin Multiplatform project that targets both Jvm and Android.

Creating separate javafx and android sample projects, but for my javafx module when I add the dependency for my multiplatform module, it is importing the `-android` variant.

```kotlin
// sample-javafx build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    // javafx plugins
    id("application")
}

// gradle stuff...

dependencies {
    // this imports the -android variant
    implementation(project("my-multiplatform-module"))
}
```

For example, when importing a published multiplatform library you can specify the `-jvm` variant, like:

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.6.0")
}
```

How can I configure the dependency for my javafx sample to import the `-jvm` variant of my kmp library project module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JVM target unable to import common classes in Kotlin multiplatform project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273345/jvm-target-unable-to-import-common-classes-in-kotlin-multiplatform-project)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. JavaFx project is setup non-multiplatform with the `kotlin("jvm")` plugin. Shouldn't that automatically say "hey, provide the -jvm artifacts"?

Comment: Could you show how have you tried? The key point is that you can should made a multiplatform module with a single JVM platform, and move all your dependencies into `jvmMain` part. Also what may be your problem, your common module should support JVM platform too, you may have only Android as you say that it imports android variant.

Comment: So, here is the setup for the KMP module:

https://github.com/05nelsonm/kmp-tor/blob/master/library/kmp-tor/build.gradle.kts

For the consuming project (`sample-javafx`) I tried using the multiplatform plugin and moving all dependencies to `jvmMain` target, and then renaming dirs from `src/main` to `src/jvmMain`. The project would not build b/c JavaFx is looking for `src/main`.I even tried using in the kmp setup `jvm("main") { withJava() } ...` which the compiler did not like either.

Comment: Your link uses some unfamiliar DSL, so I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: Correct, it is a custom plugin for setting up the source set hierarchy. Essentially, it shows that both the jvm and android targets are enabled for the kmp project which was to answer your question `Also what may be your problem, your common module should support JVM platform too,`. Other than that, it has no effect on the javafx sample module. Appreciate your time, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My wild guess is that in this case the multiplatform library is not exposing a jvm artifact explicitly, this could be a potential feature request

Alternatively you could try `publishToMavenLocal()` and consume it from local maven